# React-native facebook login via webview

Tags: android, facebook-javascript-sdk, react-native, facebook-login

Im trying to login via facebook with react-native.
And obviously for iOS it works because Im using the react-native-fbsdk package.

But what about android?
It doesn't appear that theres a package yet for native login for android?

So do I just use the regular JS sdk? How would I implement a basic webview style login?? When localStorage and such aren't available.

Sorry, just very new to react-native, and can't wrap my head around how to do this properly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a package exists. Check it [here](https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login).

It works very well.

Comment: Ive tried that one already.  Doesn't seem to work.  Just gives me an error about require('NativeModules').  and how FBLoginManager cant be found

Comment: I use it for Android and iOS and it works fine. Maybe open an issue on github for your problem. And post the link here.

Comment: It says specifically FBLoginManager.LoginBehaviours undefined.  ( and then something about NATIVE.FEEDBACK etc etc)  I even changed the login button to have the behaviour loginBehavior={FBLoginManager.LoginBehaviors.Browser}.  Still no go.  Did you just use the example code in your project?  Did it just work?

Comment: I use it this way : `FBLoginManager.loginWithPermissions(['email', 'user_friends'], function(err, data){
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
var token = (typeof data.credentials === 'undefined' ? data.token : data.credentials.token); // depends on platform`
Then I do some work with the token on my backend.

Comment: hmm, well FBLoginManager is undefined no matter what I try.  So its probably broken.  When I instantiate it - var FBLoginManager = require('NativeModules').FBLoginManager;   - returns nothing/undefined.

Comment: What version of the package are you using ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103734/discussion-between-g-hamaide-and-kylek).